# Core Plot Gallery real time plot design criteria

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-plot, scatter-plot

I few curiosities from the RealTimePlot.m of the CorePlotGallery sample real time plot setup:

```
// Plot space
CPTXYPlotSpace * plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@0.0 length:@(kMaxDataPoints - 2)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@0.0 length:@1.0];
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
```

It notes a range of points - kMaxDataPoints, initially 52, which appears to be the visible range of plot points from the initial window/view size.

The delegate newData method trims the earliest point to be added, to maintain this queue but my question is how was this value (52) derived?

Is it possible to calc at run-time this visible range even when the user pinches / zooms?

Wouldn't it better to trim the point(s) afterwards - after adding, when the quantity is known of points added, from the range beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a "magic number" derived by saying "that's looks good" rather than any empirical method. Of course you can calculate it based on the size of the plot area. Using a constant is just a shortcut. Because of the design of the app, we know that the graph won't change size on iOS, so it's a reasonable shortcut to make there.

I don't understand the last part of the question.

Comment: In the sample, when the threshold is reached a single point is removed, as one is to be added.  I was thinking that the data gathering might be scattered with an unknown of points to be added, so the quantity isn't know until afterward. In testing I moved the removal afterward and seems to be ok - maybe I like it better? How does one calculate the plot area?

Comment: We remove the old data first so the new data doesn't have to be moved when the old data is removed. It probably doesn't make much difference unless you have a lot of data. You can add or remove as many points as you need—the example just uses one for simplicity. The plot area is a subclass of `CALayer`. Call `-layoutIfNeeded` on the graph and then you can read the `bounds` of the plot area to get its size.

Comment: Not understanding how the bounds would tell me the visible range so I just experimented until, for my 16x16 symbol, 40 became the magic number!

Comment: The plot ranges of the plot space tell you the data values that will be visible. The plot area bounds tells you the physical space available to display them.

Comment: Final product: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8QzZhjxD4brNUdZcXFCUXM1OTA  THANKS a bunch!